# how to get frame of subviews of a custom UITableViewCell( Xib with autolayout ) in iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c

In generally, I can get subviews' frame in `layoutSubViews:`, but when I use autolayout in Xib and override it ,it doesn't work in iOS 8.3, it's always `CGRectZero`.

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.backIcon1.layer.cornerRadius = self.backIcon1.width / 2;
    self.backIcon1.clipsToBounds = YES;

    self.backIcon2.layer.cornerRadius = self.backIcon2.width / 2;
    self.backIcon2.clipsToBounds = YES;

    self.backIcon3.layer.cornerRadius = self.backIcon3.width / 2;
    self.backIcon3.clipsToBounds = YES;

    NSLog(@"layoutSubviews:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.backIcon1.frame));

}
```

In this method, I can't get real frame so that these codes don't work. I wanna know where can I get the real frame of subviews after storyboard finish autolayout.

Comment: can you share some code here?

Comment: `-(void)layoutSubviews {

[super layoutSubviews];
self.backIcon1.layer.cornerRadius = self.backIcon1.width / 2;
self.backIcon1.clipsToBounds = YES;

self.backIcon2.layer.cornerRadius = self.backIcon2.width / 2;
self.backIcon2.clipsToBounds = YES;

self.backIcon3.layer.cornerRadius = self.backIcon3.width / 2;
self.backIcon3.clipsToBounds = YES;

NSLog(@"layoutSubviews:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.backIcon1.frame));}`

Comment: In this method, I can't get real frame so that these codes don't work. I wanna know where can I get the real frame of subviews after storyboard finish autolayout.